# WPF storyboard animation

Tags: c#, wpf

Overall goal is to have the window fade in 0% to 80% in 1 second, stay at 80% for 3 seconds and then fade out from 80% to 0% in 1.5 seconds. The catch is, at any time if the user mouses over the window, it should go to 100% and stay there as long as the mouse is over the window. Once the mouse leaves the window, it should immediately drop to 80% and start the fade out for 1.5 seconds.

So far I've got:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0" To="0.8" />
                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:04" Duration="00:00:01.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.8" To="0.0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Not sure where to go with the mouse over thing. Do I need to move the fade out animation to some other event? If the user mouses over the window when it is fading in/out at say 70%, it should immediately go to 100%. When the mouse leaves it should go to 80% and then start the fade out after a few seconds. If I pause or stop the animation as it is, how would it know where to start from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one. Modify as per your needs

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="FadeOutBoard">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0" To="0.8" />
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:04" Duration="00:00:01.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.8" To="0.0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.MouseMove">
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeOutBoard" />
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.MouseLeave">
                <SeekStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeOutBoard" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Provide a name to the storyboard and have access a shared member variable to it. When the user mouses into the window call the member [Stop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190749(v=vs.110).aspx) to halt the storyboard. If needed set the visibility to 100% until you get a mouse exit notification. Upon the exit call a different storyboard which does the business logic you describe above.

Comment: So I'd need to move the 80% to 0% animation out to somewhere else? How would that get automatically triggered if the user never mouses over the window? This all would be easy to do in code behind, but I'm trying to keep it 100% XAML, so the user can restyle if necessary.

Comment: I am confused, you never mentioned the 100% Xaml requirement. Frankly what user is super proficient in XAML but not code behind? Any such operation can be housed in a custom control and handed to a user in any real world scenario (which allows for a user to *style* it BTW). You have two answers but they don't answer the *academic* need of that request.